# Xbee communication - blinking LED pin (ASSO/AN5)

Tags: linux, xbee

I bought two XBee series 1 adapters and have managed to set the wireless communication between them using [minicom](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/i686/minicom/) (on ArchLinux). I set the connection to be **9600 8N1** and what I write on one XBee I immediately get on another. This was a sucess.

[image]

So I tried to move the XBee on **/dev/ttyUSB2** to my [EA3141 development kit](http://www.embeddedartists.com/products/kits/lpc3141_kit.php), which has a free XBee slot. Here is the schematics of the slot:

[image]

When I connected XBee module to the EA3141 the **ON/SLEEP** LED started glowing and **ASSO/AD5** LED started blinking. What does this mean? How can this happen if XBees were already functioning on minicom?

Answer (score 1):

What device type (coordinator, router or end device)?  What is the rate of blinking?  Have you looked at the XBee documentation for that pin?  Some blink rates just indicate that you're associated or have established a network.

Are you still able to send data between the nodes?

[This question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/70600/xbee-shield-association-led) on the Electronics Stack Exchange has a description of what various blink patterns mean.